# how to change parent fxml content from action perform on child fxml component?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I created JavaFX application and want to distribute complete functionality among different FXML with hierarchy and MVC structure.

At the start time RoolLayout.fxml is load which is parent FXML

#### RootLayout.fxml

```
<BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.nikunj.drclinic.controller.RootLayoutController">
<center>
  <AnchorPane fx:id="dashboard" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
</center>
<top>
  <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <fx:include fx:id="mainMenu" source="MainMenuBar.fxml" />
     </children>
  </HBox>
</top>
</BorderPane>
```

For this used controller is RootLayoutController.java

```
public class RootLayoutController {

 @FXML
 private MainMenuBarController mainMenuBarController;

 @FXML
 private AnchorPane dashboard;

 @FXML
 private void initialize() {
    // Initialize the person table with the two columns.
 }
}
```

From inside this MainMenuBar.fxml file is also loaded which is child fxml file

#### MainMenuBar.fxml

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.nikunj.drclinic.controller.MainMenuBarController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar layoutY="2.0" prefWidth="1000.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeApplication" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Patient Detail">
            <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="addPatiendMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addPatient" text="Add Patient" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Find Patient" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

controller file for this MainMenuBar.fxml is MainMenuBarController.java

```
public class MainMenuBarController {

 @FXML
 private MenuItem addPatiendMenuItem;

 @FXML
 private MenuItem findPatientMenuItem;

 @FXML
 public void closeApplication(){
    System.exit(0);
 }

 @FXML
 public void addPatient(ActionEvent event){

 }
}
```

Now on selection of menu item addPatiendMenuItem from controller addPatient(ActionEvent event) method is called.
From this method how can i change the AnchorPane fx:id = "dashboard" which is component of the parent fxml (RootLayout.fxml) file.

Suppose i want to load content of third fxml (i.e. Dashboard.fxml) in this AnchorPane, how can i do that?

I spend lots of hours to find, how to change parent controller component from the action performed on child controller component?

Answer (score 1):

Create a property in the `MainMenuBarController` that represents the state you are changing ("view state"). Making this make sense depends on knowing a bit more about your application, but you might do something like

```
public class MainMenuBarController {
    private final BooleanProperty addPatientRequested = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    public BooleanProperty addPatientRequestedProperty() {
        return addPatientRequested ;
    }
    public final boolean isAddPatientRequested() {
        return addPatientRequestedProperty().get();
    }
    public final boolean setAddPatientReqested(boolean requested) {
        addPatientReqestedProperty().set(requested);
    }

    @FMXL
    private void addPatient(ActionEvent event) {
        setAddPatientRequested(true);
    }
}
```

Then in the "parent" controller do

```
public class RootLayoutController {

 @FXML
 private MainMenuBarController mainMenuBarController;

 @FXML
 private AnchorPane dashboard;

 @FXML
 private void initialize() {
    // Initialize the person table with the two columns.
    mainMenuBarController.addPatientRequestedProperty().addListener((obs, wasRequested, isNowRequested) -> {
        if (isNowRequested) {
            // code to execute...
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Depending on your application logic, you might want a different property, e.g. in the `MainMenuBarController` define

```
ObjectProperty<Node> display = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```

which would store the node the `RootLayoutController` is supposed to display. The structure would be similar, set that property in the `addPatient` handler method and listen to it in the `RootLayoutController`